# Android upper limit for no of OnclickListeners on an Activity

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am making a keyboard app. For what I need to know if I can assign seperate onclicklistener to each button, ie around 70 onclicklisteners on a single activity.

Is it a right way to do it??

Comment: no, the correct way is to make your Activity implement `OnClickListener`

Comment: then what about 70 different cases

Comment: can you see the param passed to `onClick` method?

Comment: won't it become slow to choose a case

Comment: slow? how many keys do you press in a second? 100? 1000? 10000? also usie a `switch` on `v.getId()` or `v.getTag()` instead of `if` `else` `if`

Answer (score 0):

Implement View.OnClickListener in your activity.Give different id for the views.

```
    public class KeyBoardActivity extends Activity  implements View.OnClickListener{
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       }
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
            //Write your code for the corresponding view ids
       }
    }
```